# Force git log to show all commits, including cherry-picked

Tags: git, git-log

*While writing, I just found the answer to this question, but will still post it to share with others.*

### Test scenario

I created a small testing repository with a merge of two branches, where one branch contains cherry-picked versions of commits already present in the other branch.

(I used `rebase -ir` to artificially craft this test history)

A regular git log shows the complete history:

```
> git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --abbrev=8
*   b1008ab1 (HEAD -> master) Merge 'alternative' into master.
|\  
| * 22a3a296 Add x.txt
| * 0af2f788 Add y.txt
* | 3856adbf Add y.txt
* | 8543e6d8 Add x.txt
|/  
* e7696150 Initial commit.
```

(I am using `git lol` alias for this, but for this question I am spelling out all the options)

However, a git log filtered to one of the files only shows the one of the respective commits that is in the main part of the branch (first merge parent):

```
> git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --abbrev=8 x.txt
* 8543e6d8 Add x.txt
```

### Question

How can I force git log to show all the commits that modify the respective file, including duplicates / cherry-picked commits?

### What I tried so far

I checked in `git help log` and found `--cherry-mark`, `--cherry-pick`, `--left-only`, `--right-only`, but none of these really make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Use `git log --full-history --simplify-merges`!

The `--full-history` already does what you want, but it lists a lot of merges which provide little information.

Adding `--simplify-merges` hides some of these merges.

Check `git help log` for detailed explanations.

This only makes a difference if a path is provided. Without a path provided, it already shows all the cherry-picked commits anyway.

```
> git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --abbrev=8 -- x.txt
* 8543e6d8 Add x.txt
```

```
> git log --simplify-merges --full-history --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --abbrev=8 -- x.txt
*   0de2139f (HEAD -> master) Merge 'alternative' into master.
|\  
| * 22a3a296 Add x.txt
* 8543e6d8 Add x.txt
```

Interestingly, this path can also be a global wildcard.

```
> git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --abbrev=8 -- *
* 2c970073 Add z.txt
* 22a3a296 Add x.txt
* 0af2f788 Add y.txt
* e7696150 (tag: BEGIN) Add a jpg image
```

```
> git log --simplify-merges --full-history --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --abbrev=8 -- *
*   0de2139f (HEAD -> master) Merge 'alternative' into master.
|\  
| * 2c970073 Add z.txt
| * 22a3a296 Add x.txt
| * 0af2f788 Add y.txt
* | 3856adbf Add y.txt
* | 8543e6d8 Add x.txt
|/  
* e7696150 (tag: BEGIN) Add a jpg image
```

### Caveats

I found that `git log` is a lot slower with `--full-history` and `--simplify-merges` on a large repo with complex history.

If a commit range is specified, e.g. `git log <parameters> master..develop -- <path>`, then a lot more merges are shown even with `--simplify-merges`.

### Useful aliases

The parameters are useful in combination with the `--graph` paramete. I already have this as `lol` and `lola` aliases (there are blog posts where people come up with these names, I did not invent them).

So I now added this to my global git config:

```
[alias]
  lol = log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --abbrev=8
  lola = log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --abbrev=8 --all
  lolf = log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --full-history --simplify-merges --abbrev=8
  lolaf = log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --full-history --simplify-merges --abbrev=8 --all
```

### Is it good that git log behaves in this way?

Perhaps not.
Check the comment by torek below.

Comment: Right: history simplification is turned on by adding files (well, *pathspecs*, to use Git's technical term) to your `git log`. `--full-history` turns history simplification off. `--simplify-merges` turns (a useful) *part* of it back on. I think Git's default options are just wrong, here: the `--full-history --simplify-merges` mode probably should be the default.

Comment: True. I was always assuming it works like that, and perhaps have already done some mistakes based on this wrong assumption.

Comment: On the other hand, if these parameters were the default, then git log would be a lot slower on big repos (this is my own experience from trying this just now, it was factor 10, from ~0.1s to ~1s, which makes a huge difference for perceived responsiveness).